# Is JNI in Java 11 not backward compatible with Java 8?

Tags: java, r, java-native-interface

[When I am installing a R package `rJava` with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923514/rjava-cant-find-usr-lib-jvm-default-java-bin-java-which-is-actually-insta),   here is the error

```
checking whether Java run-time works... yes
checking whether -Xrs is supported... yes
checking whether -Xrs will be used... yes
checking whether JVM will be loaded dynamically... no
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking whether JNI programs run... configure: error: Unable to run a simple JNI program. Make sure you have configured R with Java support (see R documentation) and check config.log for failure reason.
Warning in system(cmd) : error in running command
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
```

`rJava` can be installed with OpenJDK 8.

Why is the difference?

Is JNI in Java 11 not backward compatible with Java 8?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in `config.log`? What does the generated program look like?

Answer (score 2):

rJava uses the invocation interface and needs Java's shared libraries

In Linux, they are

- in `lib/i386` or `lib/amd64` for Java 8 (`libjvm.so` is in `lib/<arch>/server`)
- in `lib` for Java 11 (`libjvm.so` is in `lib/server`)

Once a process finds the libraries in their new place, Java 11 is backward compatible.

Comment: Thanks. How shall rJava find the libraries?

Comment: Not a clue. I'd first look for a newer release that handles the problem. Failing that I'd grep the source for JNI_CreateJavaVM and go backwards from there.

Comment: Of, course, your problem could entirely be a different one. As Botje said in their comment: what is in the log? Do you actually have a not found libjvm?